# What is the transfer function of a transformer?

Tags: transformer, transfer-function

Consider transformer as a black box. We give arbitrary input voltage \$x(t)\$, what is the output \$y(t)\$?

Naive thoughts: if \$x(t)\$ is a sin-wave, \$y(t)\$ is a sin wave also, with the same frequency, but maybe different amplitude. Every signal can be decomposed into Fourier series of sin-waves. It's seems reasonable to suppose transformer is a linear device (provides superposition), so we have \$y(t)=kx(t)\$, \$k=\operatorname{const}\$. That's wrong, because transformer can't pass DC voltage. What is the mistake here?

Comment: Probably quite complicated, but there will be at least one s-plane zero at the origin to ensure DC doesn't get through.

Comment: @Chu: it would be great if you write an explaining answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transformer equivalent circuit: -

[image]

> We give arbitrary input voltage x(t), what is the output y(t)?

You are not considering that the input is both voltage and current and that the output is the same with a bunch of various subtleties along the way such as: -

- Leakage inductances
- DC resistance (copper losses)
- Magnetization inductance
- Iron losses (eddy current and saturation)
- Secondary load impedance

And this is just a regular low frequency power transformer.

Also would you be confused in the same way with a DC blocking capacitor and resistor forming a high pass filter?

Comment: Yes, input is both voltage and current, but I'm interested only in voltage here: connect ideal voltage source x(t) to the primary coil. What is the y(t) if the transformer is ideal?

Comment: If the transformer is ideal it CAN pass dc and the output voltage is input voltage x turns_ratio. In other words it transforms power from one V/I ratio to another V/I ratio. If unloaded then the input impedance is infinite. If loaded then the input impedance depends on the load impedance and the square of the turns ratio.

Comment: I'm not confused with blocking cap, because as you say it's just an HPF. y(t) can be found via Fourier series, just attenuate amplitudes according the known frequency response. Transformer is confusing, because it should have flat freq. responce, but can't pass DC. Your comment that ideal transformer can pass DC actually solve my question and confusion, thank you.

Comment: So, you are happy with this answer?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
Referring to the above schematic
The transfer function is:

vout(s)/vin(s) = (Re*ZL*s*L1)/
(K(Z1+Ze)(Z2(Re+sL1)+ZL(Re+sL1)+sReL2))

- s  - laplace transform variable
- Re - core loss resistance
- ZL - load impedance (can be complex)
- L1- primary inductance
- L2 - secondary inductance
- Z1 - primary coil impedance (winding resistance +source resistance +leakage inductance)
- Z2 - secondary coil impedance (winding resistance + leakage inductance)
- Ze - excitation impedance ( Re*s*L1/(Re+s*L1)) (parallel of core loss resistor and primary inductance)

Comment: Posts float up and down by votes and user sorting preferences. It's better to refer to posts by author rather than "previous" as there could be several posts between Andy's and yours or yours could be above Andy's.